# Excel cell content validation with use of VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a solution to validate and highlight my cell in case false.

I tried the most promising solution: Regex. But still can not find the pattern I need.

My latest attempt was this pattern:  "*[A-Z-0-9_.]*" This works only if the cell contains only a symbol and nothing else, if the symbol is part of a string it does not work.

Problem is that it does not catch cells that have an odd character in a string of text: Example C4UNIT| or B$GROUP.

Specification  Cell can contain only capital characters and two allowed symbols Dash -  and Underbar _

This is my complete code:

```
Function ValidateCellContent()

    Sheets("MTO DATA").Select

    Dim RangeToCheck As Range
    Dim CellinRangeToCheck As Range
    Dim CollNumberFirst As Integer
    Dim CollNumberLast As Integer
    Dim RowNumberFirst As Integer
    Dim RowNumberLast As Integer

    '--Start on Column "1" and Row "3"
    CollNumberFirst = 1
    RowNumberFirst = 3

    '--Find last Column used on row "2" (Write OMI Headings)
    CollNumberLast = Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    RowNumberLast = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '--Set value of the used range of cell addresses like: "A3:K85"
    Set RangeToCheck = Range(Chr(64 + CollNumberFirst) & RowNumberFirst & ":" & Chr(64 + CollNumberLast) & RowNumberLast)
    Debug.Print "Cells used in active Range = " & (Chr(64 + CollNumberFirst) & RowNumberFirst & ":" & Chr(64 + CollNumberLast) & RowNumberLast)

    For Each CellinRangeToCheck In RangeToCheck
        Debug.Print "CellinRangeToCheck value = " & CellinRangeToCheck
        If Len(CellinRangeToCheck.Text) > 0 Then

            '--Non Printables (Space,Line Feed,Carriage Return)
            If InStr(CellinRangeToCheck, " ") _
                                        Or InStr(CellinRangeToCheck, Chr(10)) > 0 _
                                        Or InStr(CellinRangeToCheck, Chr(13)) > 0 Then
                CellinRangeToCheck.Font.Color = vbRed
                CellinRangeToCheck.Font.Bold = True

                '--Allowed Characters
            ElseIf Not CellinRangeToCheck.Text Like "*[A-Z-0-9_.]*" Then
                CellinRangeToCheck.Font.Color = vbRed
                CellinRangeToCheck.Font.Bold = True

            Else
                CellinRangeToCheck.Font.Color = vbBlack
                CellinRangeToCheck.Font.Bold = False

            End If
        End If

    Next CellinRangeToCheck

End Function
```

Comment: What is the actual pattern you are after please? Can you give some sample data and pass/fail cases?

Comment: * means "any character or combination of characters", so you could start by removing those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'we want only validate when cell content changed, if whole range is involved (i.e. more than 1 cell) then exit sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'if there is error in a cell, also color it red
If IsError(Target) Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Exit Sub
End If
'validate cell with our function, if cell content is valid, it'll return True
'if it i    s not valid, then color cell red
If Not ValidateText(Target.Value) Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
End Sub

Function ValidateText(ByVal txt As String) As Boolean
Dim i As Long, char As String
'loop through all characters in string
For i = 1 To Len(txt)
    char = Mid(txt, i, 1)
    If Not ((Asc(char) >= 65 And Asc(char) <= 90) Or char = "-" Or char = "_") Then
        'once we come upon invalid character, we can finish the function with False result
        ValidateText = False
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

ValidateText = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've originally assumed you wanted to use RegEx to solve your problem. As per your comment you instead seem to be using the `Like` operator.

---

**`Like` operator**

While `Like` accepts character ranges that may resemble regular expressions, there are many differences and few similarities between the two:

- `Like` uses `!` to negate a character range instead of the `^` used in RegEx.
- `Like` does not allow/know quantifiers after the closing bracket `]` and thus always matches a single character per pair of brackets `[]`. To match multiple characters you need to add multiple copies of your character range brackets.
- `Like` does not understand advanced concepts like *capturing groups* or *lookahead* / *lookbehind*
- probably more differences...

The unavailability of quantifiers leaves `Like` in a really bad spot for your problem. You always need to have one character range to compare to for each character in your cell's text. As such the only way I can see to make use of the `Like` operator would be as follows:

```
Private Function IsTextValid(ByVal stringToValidate As String) As Boolean

    Dim CharValidationPattern As String
    CharValidationPattern = "[A-Z0-9._-]"

    Dim StringValidationPattern As String
    StringValidationPattern = RepeatString(CharValidationPattern, Len(stringToValidate))

    IsTextValid = stringToValidate Like StringValidationPattern

End Function

Private Function RepeatString(ByVal stringToRepeat As String, ByVal repetitions As Long) As String

    Dim Result As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To repetitions
        Result = Result & stringToRepeat
    Next i
    RepeatString = Result

End Function
```

You can then pass the text you want to check to `IsTextValid` like that:

```
If IsTextValid("A.ASDZ-054_93") Then Debug.Print "Hurray, it's valid!"
```

As per your comment, a small `Worksheet_Change` event to place into the worksheet module of your respective worksheet. (You will also need to place the above two functions there. Alternatively you can make them public and place them in a standard module.):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ValidationRange As Range
    Set ValidationRange = Me.Range("A2:D5")
    Dim TargetCell As Range

    For Each TargetCell In Target.Cells

        ' Only work on cells falling into the ValidationRange
        If Not Intersect(TargetCell, ValidationRange) Is Nothing Then

            If IsTextValid(TargetCell.Text) Then
                TargetCell.Font.Color = vbBlack
                TargetCell.Font.Bold = False
            Else
                TargetCell.Font.Color = vbRed
                TargetCell.Font.Bold = True
            End If

        End If

    Next TargetCell

End Sub
```

---

**Regular Expressions**

If you want to continue down the RegEx road, try this expression:

```
[^A-Z0-9_-]+
```

It will generate a match, whenever a passed-in string contains one or more characters you don't want. All cells with only valid characters should not return a match.

**Explanation:**
`A-Z` will match all capital letters,
`0-9` will match all numbers,
`_-` will match underscore and dash symbols.
The preceding `^` will negate the whole character set, meaning the RegEx only matches characters **not** in the set.
The following `+` tells the RegEx engine to match **one or more** characters of the aforementioned set. You only want to match your input, if there is at least one illegal char in there. And if there are more than one, it should still match.

Once in place, adapting the system to changing requirements (different chars considered legal) is as easy as switching out a few characters between the [brackets].

See a [live example online](https://regexr.com/3o5jh).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, having i think issues with the complete pattern.  This is my code row:      ElseIf Not CellinRangeToCheck.Text Like "[^A-Z-0-9_-.]+" Then     This pattern selected also all good strings.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention in your question that you'd like to use the `like` operator. Things are a bit different then. And also you did not mention the dot in your text. Let me extend my answer.

Comment: @vinmeg Have a look at my edit. I've been able to verify it works within the constraints you've given. If you want to add or remove chars you can change the pattern within the `IsTextValid()` function.

Comment: Dear Inarion,  I do not get it to work. I do something wrong. If you have a excel sheet1 and enter some odd characters and some good characters in de cells in a range from A2:D5 as an example. and then run your function: can you please send me a new complete example of a function that I can run stand alone?

Comment: @vinmeg I've added a `Worksheet_Change` sub to paste into your worksheet module. You also need the `IsTextValid` and `RepeatText` functions for it to work.